# Excel copy/paste based on duplicate value in column

Tags: excel

I need a code to copy/paste based on duplicate cell values in a column. Please see example below. I want to take values from A2:B2 and paste to C1:D1 if there is duplication in E1:E2. Then loop through the rest of the spreadsheet. Any ideas? Thanks :-)

Sample

```
A         B          C         D       E    
111      222                          ABC  
333      444                          ABC  
555      666                          DEF  
777      888                          DEF
```

Result

```
A         B          C         D            E  
111      222        333       444          ABC  
333      444                               ABC  
555      666        777       888          DEF  
777      888                               DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

in Cell C2:

```
   =if(e2=e3,a3,"")
```

Copy this to every cell in C and D.